# mysql router in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mysqlrouter

There are few deployments in different namespaces in our application. Mysql is outside of the cluster and planning to use mysql router. Deployed mysql router as a service and the deployments are able to connect using kubernetes service URL. The question is should mysql router be deployed as sidecar (possible to??) to each of the deployments or run as another deployment within the cluster? If it runs as the separate deployment how the router deployment will handle the increase in requests if the app deployments are scaled up?

Comment: Looking for the best practice of MySQL router deployment. Now decided to deploy as a separate deployment instead of sidecar as auto scaling can be used to manage the load.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the **Mysql** router as **deployment** and **service**.

So when if your application scale up you can also scale the deployment with **HPA** based on the resource you are looking **CPU/Memory/Requests** etc.